# How to sort top 4 values with SQL Server which contains negative numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

Input file

```
    SN  ID
   ------------
    1   55
    2  -25
    3   62
    4  -0.05
    5   0.0
```

Output file should be after sorting

```
 SN  ID
 -------
  3  62
  1  55
  5  0.0
  4 -0.05
  2  -25
```

Using this SQL Server command need to modify by logic

```
select top 4 * 
from filename 
order by ID desc
```

Comment: Your query already looks correct.  What is the problem?

Comment: for  negative number its failing. its not considering the -ve just considering the number then sorting . may be have to use brakets or case statement somewhere . do  have any other way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as though perhaps your `ID` column is actually some sort of text, rather than numeric, type.  If so, then casting the column to a decimal and then sorting should fix the problem:

```
SELECT TOP 4 * 
FROM filename 
ORDER BY CAST(ID AS DECIMAL(10,4)) DESC;
```

Note that if the above query does work, then you should seriously consider not storing numeric information as text.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `WHERE` clause. If you need to filter only by `negative values` just add the following:

```
select top 4 * 
from filename
where ID < 0 
order by ID desc
```